# app is working on android 7 and 8 but not working on android 5 and 6

Tags: android

**App working fine on android 8 virtual device but it crashes and force closes on android 6.0.1 hardware device. MinSDK version of the app is API21 android 5. everything is working fine on virtual device app functionality database connectivity but when I try to run app on a hardware device it just show splash screen and then it closes itself show error app stopped working on and shows a lot of error in logcat which I am having understanding them. I have provided all the java code which I have used in-app for your better understanding**

Error in LogCat

```
06-16 14:27:20.657 21865-21865/com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai, PID: 21865
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai/com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai:drawable/roundstatus" (7f070082) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070082 a=-1 r=0x7f070082}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2625)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2563)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3975)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: which activity you can not load post that activity xml too

Comment: post code where you are using  `drawable/roundstatus`

Comment: use this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>`

Comment: do you have `values-<version>` folder?

Answer (score 1):

The real error is this one:

> Resource "com.example.tanishqshastri_mppolice.jansunwai:drawable/roundstatus" (7f070082) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070082 a=-1 r=0x7f070082}

Something in the definition of this drawable object is not compatible with Android 6, I can't help you more than that without more details about that drawable resource

If your app is working fine in android 8 emulator you can't assume that it will be working fine on every previous version of android! If you use an android 6 emulator image the app will crash exactly as with real device

Comment: I have used min sdk api 21 android 5 for the project and you are right app is working fine on android 7 and 8 but not working on android 5 and 6. Any Suggestion

Comment: after removing the file you mentioned app is working but I used thst file to give round corners to my view , textview , button. Can you suggest a way to acheive it with proper with android api 21 and above

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the drawable-v24 to drawable-xxhpi and it my app is working on Android 6.