# Activity doesn't start on Android 6 and not really good at Android 7

Tags: android

I can't find my mistake.
On Android 9 or 10 it works perfectly, but not on Android 6. On Andorid 7 and 8 ist works sometimes.

Target SDK is 29 and Min SDK Version is 22.

Without the image, the App starts. The imagesize is only 12 KB, png file format.

My Code:

```
My MainActivity

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonmain01;
    private Button buttonmain02;
    private Button buttonmain03;

    private long backButtonCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Activity mainActivity = this;
        mainActivity.setTitle(R.string.actionbar_name);

        buttonmain01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonfragen);
        buttonmain01.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonmain02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlosungen);
        buttonmain02.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonmain03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonthemengebiete);
        buttonmain03.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonfragen:
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Karten.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.buttonlosungen:
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, KartenLosungen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.buttonthemengebiete:
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Themengebiet.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(backButtonCount >= 1)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nochmal tippen, um die App zu beenden.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            backButtonCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo512v3" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonfragen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/titel_fragen"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/shape" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonlosungen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/titel_losungen"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/shape" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonthemengebiete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/titel_themengebiete"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/shape" />
    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I have being debugging the app, and here ist the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink, PID: 7068
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink/de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    at de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink:drawable/logo512v3" (7f0700b9) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700b9 a=-1 r=0x7f0700b9}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error inflating class ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698313/error-inflating-class-imageview)

Comment: It reads: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "de.suppenfisch.abfahrtskontrolleink:drawable/logo512v3" (7f0700b9) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700b9 a=-1 r=0x7f0700b9}` ...while `android.support` hints for, that you are building against outdated libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of drawables changes and has been expanded with newer versions of Android. Certain tags/attributes that you use to define them are not supported in older versions of Android.

In a nutshell, scale down your drawable and/or remove and unnecessary tags and attributes and work from there. A common problem for this error is the rounded tag used in drawable shapes - the rounded tag was added in either Android 8 or Android 7.

You can read a similar discussion here,

[app is working on android 7 and 8 but not working on android 5 and 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886592/app-is-working-on-android-7-and-8-but-not-working-on-android-5-and-6)